# Wordpress round image corners

Tags: image, wordpress

I currently have a Wordpress blog that displays images from a custom field I added to my posts. I am looking to round the corners of the images. When I added a div I was not able to use css that rounds the corners. How would I go about rounding the images corners?

```
    foreach (get_posts('cat='.$category->term_id) as $post) {
        echo '<li class="item">';

        setup_postdata( $post );
        $custom = get_field('face');
echo wp_get_attachment_image($custom);

echo '</li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should use CSS for that, for example:

```
.item img{
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Where `50%` just specify radius amount. You can use `px` as well as `%`. Setting it to 50% will give you circle image.